# nas'm how to use fidiv

Tags: assembly, nasm

Trying to divide a value that was placed on my floating point stack by a integer value

i checked my values right before calling fidiv and I get a seg fault, is there an obvious error here?

i commented out some lines, as i'm debugging right now

```
esubprogram:
    push    eax
    fstp    qword[ebp]  ;copy contents of st0 onto ebp          ;checked to see if values where right 
    mov eax, esi    ;move precision number into ebx         ;checked to see if values where right

    push    eax
    call    factorial   ;get the factorial value
    mov edx, eax    ;move factorial value into edx


    fld qword [ebp] ;move value of ebp onto floating point stack

    fidiv   dword [edx] ;divide ebp value by edx value

;   fstp    qword [edi] ;move divided value into edi, and pop it off the FPS

;   mov eax, edi
    pop eax
    pop eax
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are dividing by the value edx points to. This is an error, because edx isn't a pointer, its a value.

```
lea     someaddresswithspaceforfourbytes, esi
mov     [esi], edx
fidiv   dword[esi] ;divide ebp value by the value at esi
```

I don't know if you have initialized ebp with an existing address, if not, this might cause another error.

Comment: yes EBP does contain a correct value, also I'm not sure what the lea thing does....?

Comment: load effective address. You can substitute it with a "move immediate", becuase an address is a constant. Like MOV #address,register . If you don't know what I mean, look up "pointer" in wikipedia. Basically fidiv works only with a pointer, and you need a pointer (which contains an address), which points to the value for fidiv.